# Only first letter in array text file displays

Tags: c++, arrays, cout

Working on a program for my C++ course. I'm not sure where I am going wrong or what I am missing. I have an array in a text file (seating.txt) that shows a seating plan for an airplane. I need to be able to display the seating but can only seem to get the first character of the file to show up. For instance:

Row 1     *      *      X      *      X      X

and only the 'R' shows up. How do I get the entire line to display? Thank you in advance.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <ostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char tclass, seat;
int row;
int choice;
int i;
string seating[13];
string line;


ifstream seatingPlan("seating.txt");

getline(seatingPlan, line);
i = 0;

while (getline(seatingPlan, line))
{
    seating[i] = line[0];
    i++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    cout << seating[i] << "\n";

}

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sure you are only setting the 1st character of the input line here: `seating[i] = line[0];`.

Answer (score 0):

With `line[0]` you are only accessing the first character in the string. `line` is a string, not an array of strings. Use `seating[i] = line;` instead.

Comment: And 'ta da!' ... Works great. Thank you very much everyone.

Answer (score 0):

you take the first symbol from line:

```
seating[i] = line[0];
```

you should take full line:

```
seating[i] = line;
```